# Read the first line of the file including carriage return line feed

Tags: powershell, carriage-return

What I am trying to achieve here is to read the first only line of a text file to the string and capture carriage return line feed (or any other non printable characters) altogether as well, but neither without reading full contents of the file nor the second line (if present) and at this point I am not sure how to achieve this using PowerShell. Please note, the script is going to be dealing with the files of size ranging up to 30GB in size, so reading all the file contents into the memory is clearly no option for me (timewise as well).

Using the below I am able to read in the first line only but `CR/LF` characters get trimmed at the end of the line:

```
   $File = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg $PathFull
   $Header = $File.ReadLine()
   $File.Close()
```

I can also get the first line using:

```
$Header = (Get-Content -Path $PathFull -Head 1)
```

but, as expected `Get-Content` reads each line as a string into collection of objects and `CR/LF` characters here also get lost at the first line as well.

The only way I was able to read in the `CR/LF` characters was using the `-Raw` key with `Get-Content` commandlet, but that didn't solve my original problem as it read the whole contents of the file first and using both `-Raw` and `-Head` keys at the same time is not allowed.

Please note, that adding these characters back to the string manually after reading the line with something like:

```
$Header = $Header + "$([Char]13)$([Char]10)"
```

is not an option for me as well as my goal is purely to determine whether the line I read was correctly delimited with either combination of `CR/LF`, `CR` only or `LF` only characters and I have no knowledge of this before reading the actual line.

Any help on this topic is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Read()` method to read each character one at a time until you encounter either a carriage return or a line feed:

```
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader D:\file.txt    
do{
    $c = $reader.Read()
    $result = if($c -eq 13){
        if(-not $reader.EndOfStream -and 10 -eq $reader.Read()){
            'CRLF'
        }else{
            'CR'
        }
    }elseif($c -eq 10){
        'LF'
    }
}until($result)
$reader.Dispose()

return $result
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer! I have been able to adapt this approach to my script successfully. On a second note, do you think of any similar ideas for reading the file footer (last line) in the same manner?

Comment: If it can help at this point I already have the count of characters in the header, which is anticipated to be the same in length for every line (dealing here with fixed length files only).

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN / [StreamReader.ReadLine Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed.

The ReadLine() method implicitly solves your goal/problem. It reads data until it reaches CR, LF or CR/LF. The only special case you may want to handle is when your file has a single line (no EOL character(s) present, only EOF).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see your point here, but how do I determine then which of these characters has been detected specifically (CR, LF or CR/LF) as that is my goal here to determine?